# jquery overriding form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I want to submit a form using AJAX. Below is my code. It is in external JS file:

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    alert("come");
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var dataSplit = data.split("-");
            if (dataSplit[0] === "done") {
                swal("Job Done!", "Your request is done!", "success");
            } else if (dataSplit[0] === "error") {
                swal("Cancelled", "Your request cant be done :(", "error");
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary request cant be done :(", "error");
        }
    });
});
```

It works fine, but my problem is that I want to confirm the form before submitting. This is the code in my JSP file:

```
$('#Form').submit(function () {
    $.confirm({
        title: 'Confirm!',
        content: 'Simple confirm!',
        buttons: {
            confirm: function () {
                $.alert('Confirmed!');
               // $('#Form').submit();
            },
            cancel: function () {
                $.alert('Canceled!');
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This code is OK. Now my problem is how to call the submit function in the external file whiting confirm button function when i remove comment in this `//$('#Form').submit();` code in button function its call submit function in jsp file repeatedly how can i call external file submit function

Comment: I tried to improve the grammar, but the wording in the last paragraph is horrible and absolutely uncomprehensible. If your English is not that good, then try to use simple sentences and use white space for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Maybe your `form` includes the attribute `action`, So you should delete the attribute `action`, Like this:

```
// before
<form action="xx.jsp">
</form>

// after
<form>
</form>
```

Hope can help you~

Comment: no its not working because i getting action value in external submit method so i can't remove that

Comment: you can remove it, and set your action in your function, like this:
$.ajax({
  url: 'some.jsp',
})

you should try it, believe me.

Comment: or you can do this:
<form data-action="xx.jsp"></form>
url: $(this).attr('data-action')

Comment: now its call both function in same time but i want call internal function before external function and call external function only internal function confrimation is true

Answer (score 0):

i found something, i'm change submit button type to button and call confirm function when click on that button and is it true submit the form